# Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to consume a REST service in android and I am getting the following error:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to  http://localhost:8080 refused
```

I have introduced the permission: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
I am running the code in a emulator and it works but when I try to run in my smartphone it fails.

PD: When I run in the emulator I use http://10.0.2.2:8080.

```
public boolean checkConnection(){
    String res = "";
    boolean serverUp = false;

    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:8080/prueba_conexion");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/prueba_conexion");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String linea = "";
        while ((linea = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            res += linea;
        }

        serverUp = Boolean.parseBoolean(res);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return serverUp;
}
```

Comment: post your code here...

Comment: Localhost means that the service you are consuming is running on the same device from which you calling (your phone). If that is not correct you are using the wrong network/IP address for accessing the REST service.

Comment: Connect the phone to the same wifi network, then user your local IP instead of localhost.

Comment: I need to connect with 3G/4G connection.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost doesnt work on your phone, because it refers to the phone itself.

You need to get your local IP address and use it instead ie. 192.168.something.something usually.

Comment: I have changed my url to 192.168.X.X and now I get another error: 0x5ad46aa0: Failed to ResTable::remove() cookie = 0x3, not last table. mHeaders.size() = 4. Warning for spontaneous crashes when the garbage collector runs.